# Wrong solution of a linear equation, or why does A*(A\B) not equal B?

Tags: matlab, octave, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, least-squares

How is it possible that the result of `A*(A\D)` below is not equal to `D` ?

[image]

It should yield `D` - here is an extract of the Octave documentation :

> Systems of linear equations are ubiquitous in numerical analysis. To
>   solve the set of linear equations Ax = b, use the left division
>   operator, ‘\’: x = A \ b

Below is the code for those who want to try it:

```
A = [1,1,1;0,0,0;2,1,2;2,1,2;3,5,6]
D = [1;2;3;4;5]
% A is of rank 3:
rank(A)
% therefore the system Ax=D has a unique solution
x = A\D
% but Octave has not given the good solution:
A*x
```

Somebody says me that Matlab yields exactly the same result.

**EDIT 10/10/2012:** After having read the answers, let me point where I did a serious mistake: the claim *"A is of rank 3 therefore the system Ax=D has a unique solution"* is absolutely wrong ! By the way the piece of documentation shown above is quite disconcerting.

Comment: Why should `A*(A\D)` be the same as `D`?

Comment: @phimuemue Because this is exactly the goal of the left division operator. I have edited my post to add the content of the documentation about this operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A` has 5 rows, and so is `D`. Both of them have 3 columns. Therefore, you have an overdetermined system of 5 equations with 3 variables. In most of the cases, it means that you cannot solve the equations exactly, because you have too many constraints.

Once you do

```
x = A\D;
```

you get the least squares solution.

```
 0.8333
-1.5000
 1.6667
```

What is this solution? It is a solution that minimizes the sum of squares of errors. Let's calculate the error:

```
  r = A*x-D;
  totalError = sum( r.^2);
```

It means that you will not be able to find any `x` such that `sum(sqr(A*x-D))` has smaller error.

Small remark : In your case, you also have a row of zeroes - which causes the actual number of equations to become 4

Let's take a look again at `A*(A\D)`:

```
>> A* (A\D)

ans =

    1.0000
         0
    3.5000
    3.5000
    5.0000
```

That looks familiar! Very close to [1;2;3;4;5]. The first and the last rows are the same. The second is zero, because you put a line of zeros. In the 3rd and 4th rows, you had exactly the same lines in A, but different value in B, that corresponds to

```
2*x+ 1*y + 2*z  = 3;
2*x+ 1*y + 2*z  = 4;
```

And you've got their average! It makes sense, because the average is the value that minimizes the sum of distances to 3 and 4.

---

Here is a simpler example, suppose you want to solve the following system of equations:

```
   x = 1;
   x = 2;
```

Obviously, `x` cannot be `1` and `2` at the same time. The solution that minimizes the sum of squares of errors is `1.5`

```
   A = [1;1];
   b = [1;2];
   A\b
   ans =
    1.5000
```

Comment: Upvoted, however I note that `x = A\D` should return `[0.833; -1.5; 1.9997]`

Comment: I realized that my comment has a mistake in it too, however you seem to have noticed and corrected it :)

Comment: Thank you ! I was thinking that Octave would return a warning in such a situation.

Answer (score 2):

Your system `A` is overdetermined (A is rectangular), hence you [do not solve your system exactly](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html):

> **Rectangular Matrices**
>   If A is rectangular, mldivide returns a least-squares solution. MATLAB solves overdetermined systems with QR factorization (see qr). For an underdetermined system, MATLAB returns the solution with the maximum number of zero elements.

Comment: Thanks ! The Octave documentation is not so precise.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent then please submit a patch for the documentation All manual chapters are here http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/default/doc/interpreter Submit patches to the bug tracker at http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave

Comment: @carandraug I don't understand how to use the files in your first link. The documentation I talked about is the following one: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/octave.pdf (section 1.2.4). It only claims that the left division operator solves a linear system.

Comment: @carandraug since I do not need to be part of this discussion, please take it somewhere else, e.g. under the OP.